# Maui Blazer save a text file

Tags: blazor, razor-class-library, maui-blazor

I'm new to .net Maui, I have a shared RCL, razor class library, project that is being shard between Blazor WASM and Blazor Maui.

Following this blog, in RCL I have a shared code that can save a file

save a file client-side using Blazor
https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-do-i-generate-and-save-a-file-client-side-using-blazor

This works fine in Blazor WASM, but on .net Maui it saves the file with the name as **"Unconfirmed 396471.crdownload"**  is there a way to fix this ?
or alternatively fire an event from RCL to be handled in .NET MAUI Blazor app to start file save process using windows native code?